# How Do I add a widget to an existing dashboard in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am trying to add a widget to a dashboard in my cloud formation template in yaml. I am trying to make it so that for every stack that is deployed, it will automatically create a widget for this master dashboard to help monitoring. However, whenever I deploy, it says dashboard "already exists" and then fails. I want to simply add to this existing dashboard.

```
  AutoScalingDashboardMetrics:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties: 
      DashboardBody: !Sub |
        {
          "start": "-PT9H",
          "periodOverride": "inherit",
          "widgets": [
              {
                "type":"metric",
                "properties":{
                    "metrics": [
                        [ "AWS/AutoScaling", "GroupTotalInstances", "AutoScalingGroupName", "${AWS::StackName}", { "period": 300 } ],
                        [ ".", "GroupStandbyInstances", ".", ".", { "period": 300 } ],
                        [ ".", "GroupDesiredCapacity", ".", ".", { "period": 300 } ]
                    ],
                    "view": "timeSeries",
                    "stacked": false,
                    "region": "{AWS::Region}",
                    "title": "ASG Instances: ${AWS::StackName}",
                    "period": 300
                }
              }
          ]
        }
      DashboardName: test
```

Answer (score 0):

To add something to an existing dashboard with CloudFormation, that dashboard must be managed with CloudFormation.

What you can do:

1. Go to the existing dashboard, do `Action` -> `View/Edit source` and
   copy the source into your CloudFormation code.
2. Rename the existing dashboard.
3. Build the dashboard with CloudFormation.
4. Add what you need to CloudFormation template and update stack.